# Flutter Firebase Database information not saving?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, state, flutter

I'm creating the user Follows / Unfollows portion of my app and I'm coming up with several issues.  The latest deals with following a fellow user and saving some reference info under a "follows" node.  I'm looking at my Firebase console while doing this in my simulator and noticed the information appears correctly in green and 1 second later changes to red in order to delete.  Here is how I'm saving things...

```
Future<Null> follow() async {
    await fb
        .child('users/${currentUser}/Follows/${friendsUID}')
        .update({"name": userName, "photo": userImage});
  }
```

I'm running the following code before my Widget build in order to determine if the user is being followed and which buttons should build accordingly....

```
 void _friends() {
    fb.child("users/${userid}/Follows/${id}").onValue.listen((Event event) {
      setState(() {
        // this will return true or false which is what you want based on your code :)
        friends = event.snapshot.value == null;
      });
    });
  }
```

And occasionally I'm receiving the following error message, I'm not sure if its related to saving the Firebase though...

```
setState() called after dispose(): FriendsVideoPageState#51581(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
```

Comment: Hi @Charles, did  you get any solution for this issue?